# Do I still need to water transplanted plants if they're being transplanted into a flood plain?

Tags: transplanting, soil-amendment, rhubarb

My mom, and I just transplanted 10 rhubarb plants (thinning 6 that were planted near each other), and I was wondering if there would be enough moisture in the soil to not need to water them (suction noise when digging with a shovel).

I put a heap (about 2X the hole size) of myceliated wood chips (Stropharia Rugosoannulata) in the area to replace the soil. so that it would be a super rich replacement when broken down.

Answer (score 1):

The rhubarb seems fine in a soil that stays black, and sticky without water penetration to the shovel when dry, but I'm watering it anyways to make sure it gets the water needed.